# How to concatanate the result of two Linux commands

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, tr

Is there an easy way to concatenate the result of two Linux commands, in one line (i.e., without using variables)?

I pull the local outdoor temperature from a nearby weather station. The result today is:

```
5.2
```

I simply want to add the units, so the result should look like this:

```
5.2°C
```

An example command, that almost gives me what I want is:

```sh
wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)' ; printf "°C\n"
```

Comment: There should be [some kind of space between "5.2" and "°C"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15953).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or do it inside-out:

```
printf "%s°C\n" "$(wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)')"
```

So that the results from `wget...|grep...` are collected as a command-substitution and inserted into the `%s` in the `printf`.

Answer (score 8):

`echo`, for example, just prints all the arguments you give it. You can use command substitution to turn the output of a command into a string.

```
echo $(wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)') °C
```

Answer (score 5):

Delete the carriage return at the end of `wget`’s output:

```
wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)' | tr -d '\n' ; printf "°C\n"
```

Comment: I might have used `sed -e `s/$/°C/` to append characters at the end of a line and side-step the separate-command concatenation problem entirely.  The `grep` can potentially be folded into the `sed -n`, too, if you can do what's necessary without PCREs.

Answer (score 2):

Single **sed**

As suggested by Stephen Kitt, although this isn't an exact answer to the question...

```
$ wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | sed -n 's/.*Tn= \(.*\)&deg.*/\1°C/p'
3.8°C
```

`\1` is a backref to what is matched inside the parentheses

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665574) for explanation on what the combination of `-n` and `/p` does.